# How to deploy angular2 app with HTML5 Mode with docker container

Tags: angular, docker, angular2-routing, html5mode

How to deploy angular2 app with docker container,

Currently I am using Node js with express to serve my app content,

index.js

```
 // set server port. SERVER_PORT varibale will come from Dockerfile
var port = process.env.SERVER_PORT;
if (!port) {
    port = 3000;
}
// set internal communication url
global.internalURL = "http://localhost:" + port;

var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,access_token');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

var router = express.Router(express);
app.use("/testapp", router);

router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("server on " + port);
});
```

my base URL

```
<base href="/testapp/">
```

My Docker File

```
FROM node
COPY ./package-deploy.json /package.json
COPY ./index.js /index.js
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY ./dist /dist
RUN npm install --only=production
ENV SERVER_PORT 80
EXPOSE 80
CMD pm2-docker index.js
```

Building

> ng build
>
> docker build -t testapp:v1 .

This method works perfectly. But I like to know , is there any better way to Run Angular 2 App with HTML5 Mode?

Answer (score 1):

Building an angular application in a docker image is pretty simple once you know how to:

1. Build the application `ng build --prod`
2. Add `.htaccess` file
3. Copy `dist` to an `httpd` image.
4. Profit

Using this method will remove express logic from your code, meaning that you'll have to manage less code and concentrate on the application itself.

Example `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM httpd:2.4

COPY ./dist /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

COPY ./.htaccess /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

`.htaccess` file you need to have at the root of your application:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Feel free to look for more details on the project if you need.

**Edit:**

The Dockerfile I linked to you is built in a CI process where the app building has already been done. Of course you have to build the application before building the image.

I'm doing that because this way, the original typescript code and the css are not served on the web, so they are unreachable from the website itself.

Comment: Will it support HTML5 mode?

Comment: I don't know about the html5 specs but I think it should

Comment: It not working with HTML5 Mode. Sorry I didn't that in question clearly before. now I edited the question.

Comment: @vimalprakash do you have any document reference on standards you need to meet?

Comment: Hi @Supamiu , Please look this document by angular 2 : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html, in this search for "Appendix: LocationStrategy and browser URL styles" I like to have a PathLocationStrategy

Comment: @vimalprakash I updated my answer with more configurations, I tried it on local just a couple of minutes ago and it worked well.

Comment: @downvoter Could you pelase explain your downvote? I would like to improve my answer if you found something bad in it

Comment: It didn't work for me without some changes to apache config: `RUN sed -i -e 's/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_rewrite.so\)/\1/' -e 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` and `COPY ./.htaccess /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/`